# asyncmongo nested query

Tags: python, mongodb

I store relations of items and it's attributes in structure:

```
{'item': <item_id>,
 'rel_name': 'sizes:4762',
 'rel_type': 'sizes',
 'rel_value': '4762'}
```

And have mongoDB query that works perfectly in mongodb shell:

```
db.relations.distinct(
    'rel_name',
    {item:{
        $in: db.items.distinct('id', {
            'attributes.cat': {$in:[477]},
            'attributes.sizes': {$in:[4762,5071,5072,5089,5555,903]}
        })
    }}
)
```

And need to run it with asyncmongo to avoid overhead with getting values of items.distinct and pass it back to mongo (it might be over 10000)
Maybe is there a way to pass whole query as string and get result?

Comment: Found solution. If you don't need to use cursor and get all data (as in my 'distinct' query) you can use db.eval. But beware, this method won't work on shards and [by default db.eval() requires a write lock so it will block all read/write operations while it runs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution)

Answer (score 1):

This only works on the shell and on the db.eval() because you would be running javascript.
At the end you will eventually need to send 2 different commands to mongo server to

1. collect all sizes from the db.items collection, which are in the list you are sending
2. match with those with the 'real_name: id' for each one.

If you use an asynchronous framework, the only thing you will be optimizing is that for each cursor.next() event you can process the second query. Still these are 2 individual different queries you will be sending.

Comment: Could you please illustrate your solution? Good thing about cursors but how to connect cursors of two queries and avoid passing tons of data between asyncmongo and mongo or making tons of queries? Querying for each id gives different result in need of post filtration and aggergation.